# Unexpected Antlr4 parser errors

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I found an odd behavior in Antlr4 (I tried versions 4.10 and 4.10.1 with the same result).

When I try to use the grammar

```
grammar Paths;

cfg: NL? (entry (NL | EOF))* EOF;

entry: path ':' value;

path: SEGMENT ('.' SEGMENT)*;

value: USTRING;

SEGMENT: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;

USTRING: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;

NL: [\n\r]+;

WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

on the string `"key1:value1\nkey2.sub:value2\nkey3.sub1.sub2:value3"`, I see error messages:

```
line 1:5 mismatched input 'value1' expecting {':', '.'}
line 2:9 mismatched input 'value2' expecting {':', '.'}
line 3:15 mismatched input 'value3' expecting {':', '.'}
```

If I replace `value` definition with `value: SEGMENT`, everything works as expected.

What is wrong in the first definition?

The output of tree in both cases is the same:

```
(cfg (entry (path key1) : (value value1)) \n (entry (path key2 . sub) : (value value2)) \n (entry (path key3 . sub1 . sub2) : (value value3)) <EOF> <EOF>)
```

I tried to simplify the grammar:

```
grammar Paths;

cfg: NL? (entry (NL | EOF))* EOF;

entry: path ':' value;

path: SEGMENT;

value: USTRING;

SEGMENT: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;

USTRING: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;

NL: [\n\r]+;

WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

In this case I have errors (the parsed string is `"key1:value1\nkey2:value2\nkey3:value3"`):

```
line 1:5 mismatched input 'value1' expecting USTRING
line 2:5 mismatched input 'value2' expecting USTRING
line 3:5 mismatched input 'value3' expecting USTRING
```

And again everything is fine if I replace `USTRING` with `SEGMENT` in the `value` definition.
Output is

```
(cfg (entry (path key1) : (value value1)) \n (entry (path key2) : (value value2)) \n (entry (path key3) : (value value3)) <EOF> <EOF>)
```

Answer (score 2):

That’s because ANTLR’s Lexer processes the input stream of characters to produce a token stream, and the parser processes the token stream.  The recursive descent parsing in ANTLR is processing the token stream and has no impact on how the Lexer views input.

The Lexer rules `SEGMENT` and `USTRING` are identical, as a result, both rules will match exactly the same run of input characters.  When that happens, ANTLR will match the first rule, so they’ll all be `SEGMENTS tokens.

If you’ve run through the standard setup (and created the `grun` alias you can run it with the `-tokens option to get a dump of your token stream.  This is generally a good idea for validating that you Lexer rules are creating the token stream you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Antlr assigns to values types '''SEGMENT'''. Lexer ignores grammar and if there are tokens that could be assigned to different types, lexer assigns them to a single random type.

This piece of code helped me:

```
val lexer = PathsLexer(CharStreams.fromString("key1:value1\nkey2.sub:value2\nkey3.sub1.sub2:value3"))
val tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
tokens.fill()
println(tokens.getTokens.asScala.map { token =>
  s"$token: ${token.getType} -> ${lexer.getVocabulary.getDisplayName(token.getType)}"
}.mkString("\n"))
```

Probably I need to learn more about Antlr modes.

Comment: This doesn’t have anything to do with modes.  It’s just how the Lexer handles a “tie” between two Lexer rules matching the same run of input characters (it will use the first rule defined in the grammar)

Comment: @MikeCargal Actually modes helped me. I just created a ValueMode, pushed it after key-value separator (':') and popped it after entry separator (new line).

Now I'm trying to figure out how to work with single and triple quotes...